# How to create an ASP.NET MVC project dynamically using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

My purpose is to create a customized code generator tool that will create an ASP.NET solution that includes an ASP.NET MVC project with default directory structure, multiple class library projects, all the .csproj files, web.config and the .sln file. What is the way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean a guidance package, or a stand-alone tool?

Comment: I want to create a stand-alone tool that will help setup an MVC project with some pre-built library projects and assets like css, js and images.

Comment: Why go through all the trouble? Wouldn't it just be easier to keep a pre-configured solution in a read-only repository and just export it every time you need a fresh solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could always use the Visual Studio extensibility tools to create a new project template (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/vstudio/ff677564) This would allow you to customize the files that are added to the project.

For a standalone tool, I think you would just need to create the project you want to end up with and then write a C# program to write files in a similar way. Visual Studio project files and solution files are just plain text xml files which you can author yourself